# How can I adjust this code to not run out of RAM on infinite scroll website?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opensea

Here is my current code which works, but I end up running out of ram before reaching bottom:

```
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
i = 1

links_list = []

while True:
    # scroll one screen height each time
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    try:
        scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    except WebDriverException:
        break
    else:
        pass
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i} + {extrascroll});".format(screen_height=screen_height, extrascroll=extrascroll, i=i))
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    try:
        links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='styles__StyledLink-sc-l6elh8-0 ekTmzq Asset--anchor']")
    except WebDriverException:
        break
    for link in links:
        print(link.get_attribute("href"))
        links_list.append(link.get_attribute("href"))
        #file.write(link.get_attribute("href") + '\n')
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    #if i == 15:
    #    break
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break

#remove duplicate links
links_list = list(dict.fromkeys(links_list))

for link in links_list:
    file2.write(link + '\n')

file2.close()
```

As you can tell from the code, I have to continuously grab links as I go down the page due to Opensea dynamically loading the items as you go down.

The website I am trying to scrape from is [website](https://opensea.io/collection/zed-run-official). Is there any other better way to scrape from this website? I'm still new to coding and selenium so I don't know a whole bunch, I'm also open to trying other web scraping solutions that might help, I have ran out of ideas now.

If you need any more information please let me know in the comments. (P.S I know Opensea has an API but they haven't created an API for the listing type that I need)

Comment: What error do you see which makes you feel you are _running out of ram_?

Comment: My chrome shows up with the "oops.. you have run out of memory" error and closes the website essentially.

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: You could delete things from the DOM, that's about the only thing that will help

Comment: how would i go about doing that?